# Inverted mouse colors not working while running f.lux

Tags: windows-7, mouse, f.lux

I have set my mouse up to show inverted colors. The problem is that when I got to class today after removing my laptop from the other monitors it was connected to; the mouse color inversion was simply showing a white mouse on all backgrounds. I tried to restart my laptop, but it was still doing this. Is there a fix to this issue? I also am running f.lux on my machine.

Comment: Please, do not add "[SOLVED]" to your question titles. There are visual indicators to the questions with accepted answers, changing the title just adds noise.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest f.lux (v4.55) right-click the tray icon and go to [Options and Smart lighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arUn3.jpg).

Tick the option `Software mouse cursor when needed`, this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well it would appear that the new version of f.lux doesn't seem to play nice when I disconnect my laptop from my expanded monitors. **My solution was to disable f.lux.**